# Adding authorization to a Google contacts request

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to get a google users contacts using Oauth. However the code examples and my lack of knowledge are currently making that difficult. I am using this page as a reference. 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?csw=1#running_the_sample_code

This is where I get confused.

```
 using Google.Contacts;
 using Google.GData.Contacts;
 using Google.GData.Client;
 using Google.GData.Extensions;
     // ...
     RequestSettings settings = new RequestSettings("<var>YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME</var>");
     // Add authorization token.
     // ...
     ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(settings);
     // ...
```

I don't know what I need to fill in there, or if that code is complete enough or how to ask for a specific users contacts and I have a hard time understanding the documentation. I'm a novice at best. Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example should help you get started:

```
class OAuth2Demo {
    private static string clientId;
    private static string clientSecret;
    private static string domain;

    private static string applicationName = "Test-OAuth2";

    // Installed (non-web) application
    private static string redirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

    // Requesting access to Contacts API and Groups Provisioning API
    private static string scopes = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/ https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/groups/";

    /// <summary>
    /// This console application demonstrates the usage of OAuth 2.0 with the Google Apps APIs.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">Command-line arguments: args[0] is
    /// the client ID, args[1] is the client secret, args[2] is domain name.
    /// </param>
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        if (args.Length != 3) {
            Console.WriteLine("Syntax: OAuth2Demo <client_id> <client_secret> <domain>");
        } else {
            clientId = args[0];
            clientSecret = args[1];
            domain = args[2];

            OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters() {
                ClientId = clientId,
                ClientSecret = clientSecret,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                Scope = scopes
            };

            string url = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters);
            Console.WriteLine("Authorize URI: " + url);
            parameters.AccessCode = Console.ReadLine();

            OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);

            // Testing OAuth 2.0 with a Request-based library
            RunContactsSample(parameters);

            // Testing OAuth 2.0 with a Service-based library
            RunGroupsSample(parameters, domain);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Send authorized queries to a Request-based library
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="service"></param>
    private static void RunContactsSample(OAuth2Parameters parameters) {
        try {
            RequestSettings settings = new RequestSettings(applicationName, parameters);
            ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(settings);

            Feed<Contact> f = cr.GetContacts();
            foreach (Contact c in f.Entries) {
                Console.WriteLine(c.Name.FullName);
            }
        } catch (AppsException a) {
            Console.WriteLine("A Google Apps error occurred.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", a.ErrorCode);
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input: {0}", a.InvalidInput);
            Console.WriteLine("Reason: {0}", a.Reason);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Send authorized queries to a Service-based library
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="service"></param>
    private static void RunGroupsSample(OAuth2Parameters parameters, string domain) {
        try {
            GOAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory = new GOAuth2RequestFactory("apps", applicationName, parameters);

            GroupsService service = new GroupsService(domain, applicationName);
            service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;

            GroupFeed feed = service.RetrieveAllGroups();
            foreach (GroupEntry group in feed.Entries) {
                Console.WriteLine(group.GroupName);
            }
        } catch (AppsException a) {
            Console.WriteLine("A Google Apps error occurred.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", a.ErrorCode);
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input: {0}", a.InvalidInput);
            Console.WriteLine("Reason: {0}", a.Reason);
        }
    }
}
```

I got it from [here](http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/clients/cs/samples/oauth2_sample/oauth2demo.cs).
All the best with your app.

Comment: What is the parameters.AccesCode supposed to be?